# How to prevent two JavaScript files from executing simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, validation

I have two JavaScript files. One is running validation, and other have ajax plugin that sends form after validation.
When I attached these files in the header section, then they simultaneously run, but if I attach these two files in the body, then validation runs as it should but ajax call not working.
There is no any error on the console as well.
..
What you people suggests?

AjaxCall.js

```
$(document).ready(function() { 


    var options = { 
       beforeSubmit:  showRequest,  // pre-submit callback 
       success:       showResponse,  // post-submit callback 
        url: 'quoteProcess.php',         // override for form's 'action' attribute 
        type: 'post',        // 'get' or 'post', override for form's 'method' attribute 
       clearForm: true        // clear all form fields after successful submit 
    }; 
            // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
            $('#testform').ajaxForm(options);
           }); 

  // pre-submit callback 
function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {

    $('.modal').show();
    return true; 
}   
  function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
      $('.modal').hide();
    alert( '\n\nYour Quote has been Recieved ! \n' + responseText +
        '\n'); 
window.location.replace("http://localhost/lamozine/quote.php");

}
```

validation.js

```
(function($){

  var functions = {
    reset: resetValidation
  };

  var settings;
  var _reqForm;
  var _indicatorTemplate = '<span class="error-indicator" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-hidden="true"></span>';
  var _summaryTemplate = '<div id="errorSummary" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" tabindex="-1"><p>{0}</p></div>';
  var _validationTypes = {
    required: {msg: ' is required' },
    tel: {msg: ' is not a valid phone number' },
    email: {msg: ' is not a valid email address' },
    date: {msg: ' is not a valid date'},
    number: {msg: ' is not a valid number'}
  };

  $.fn.attrvalidate = function() {
     if (!this.is('form')) {
      return this;
    }

    if (typeof arguments[0] === 'string') {
      var property = arguments[1];
      var newArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
      newArgs.splice(0, 1);
      functions[arguments[0]].apply(this, newArgs);
    } else {
      setupFormValidation.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    return this;
  };


  function resetValidation(){
    $(_reqForm).find('input, select, textarea, fieldset').removeClass('invalid');
    $(_reqForm).find('.error-indicator').attr('aria-hidden', true);
    $(_reqForm).find('#errorSummary').remove();
  }

  function setupFormValidation(options){
    settings = $.extend({
      showFieldIndicator: true,
      showErrorSummary: true,
      errorSummaryMsg: 'Please fix the following issues before continuing:',
      validateTel: true,
      telRegex: /^\+*[\d-()]{7,20}$/,
      validateEmail: true,
      emailRegex: /^(\S+@\S+)*$/,
      validateDate: true,
      validateNumber: true
    }, options);

    _reqForm = this;
    initialiseValidation();
    $(_reqForm).bind('submit', handleSubmit);
  }

  function initialiseValidation(){
    var _groupsInitialised = [];
    $(_reqForm).find('input, select[required], textarea[required]').each(function(){
      if (isRadioGroup($(this)) && $(this).is('[required]')) {
        var groupName = $(this).attr('name');
        if ($.inArray(groupName, _groupsInitialised) === -1) {
          $(this).attr('data-do-validate', true);
          setFieldName($(this));

          if (settings.showFieldIndicator){
            $(this).parents('fieldset').first().append($(_indicatorTemplate));
          }

          $(_reqForm).find('input[name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').each(function(){
            $(this).change(function(){
              handleFieldChanged($(this));
            });
          });
          _groupsInitialised.push(groupName);
        }
      } else {
        if ($(this).is('[required]') ||
          (settings.validateTel && $(this).is('input[type="tel"]')) ||
          (settings.validateEmail && $(this).is('input[type="email"]')) ||
          (settings.validateDate && $(this).is('input[type="date"]')) ||
          (settings.validateNumber && $(this).is('input[type="number"]'))){

          $(this).attr('data-do-validate', true);
          setFieldName($(this));

          if (settings.showFieldIndicator){
            if (($(this).is('input[type="radio"]') || $(this).is('input[type="checkbox"]')) && $(this).next('label').length > 0) {
              $(this).next('label').after($(_indicatorTemplate));
            } else {
              $(this).after($(_indicatorTemplate));
            }
          }

          $(this).change(function(){
            handleFieldChanged($(this));
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }

  function handleFieldChanged(elem){
    var validationResult = validateField(elem);
    if (validationResult.isValid) {
      clearFieldError(elem);
    } else {
      var fieldMsg = getFieldMessage(elem, validationResult.type);
      showFieldError(elem, fieldMsg);
    }
  }

  function handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formValid = true;
    var errorMessages = [];

    $(_reqForm).find('#errorSummary').remove();

    $(_reqForm).find('[data-do-validate="true"]').each(function(){
      var validationResult = validateField($(this));
      if (!validationResult.isValid) {
        var fieldMsg = getFieldMessage($(this), validationResult.type);
        errorMessages.push({ elem: $(this).prop('id'), msg: fieldMsg });
        showFieldError($(this), fieldMsg);
        formValid = false;
      } else {
        clearFieldError($(this));
      }
    });

    if (!formValid) {
      if (settings.showErrorSummary) {
        showErrorSummary(errorMessages);
      }
      return false;
    } else {
      if (typeof(settings.submitFunction) !== 'undefined') {
        settings.submitFunction();
      } else {
        _reqForm[0].submit();
      }
    }
  }

  function validateField(elem){
    if (!elem.is(':visible') || elem.parents('[aria-hidden="true"]').length > 0){
      return { isValid: true };
    }

    if (elem.is('input[type="radio"]')) {
      if (elem.is('[required]')){
        if (isRadioGroup(elem)) {
          return { isValid: ($(_reqForm).find('input[name="' + elem.attr('name') + '"]:checked').length > 0), type: _validationTypes.required };
        } else {
          return { isValid: elem.is(':checked'), type: _validationTypes.required };
        }
      } else {
        return { isValid: true };
      }
    } else if (elem.is('input[type="checkbox"]')) {
      return { isValid: (!elem.is('[required]') || elem.is(':checked')), type: _validationTypes.required };
    } else {
      if (elem.is('[required]') && (elem.val() === '')) {
        return { isValid: false, type: _validationTypes.required };
      } else if (settings.validateTel && elem.is('input[type="tel"]')) {
        return { isValid: settings.telRegex.test(elem.val().replace(/ /g, '')), type: _validationTypes.tel };
      } else if (settings.validateEmail && elem.is('input[type="email"]')) {
        return { isValid: settings.emailRegex.test(elem.val().trim()), type: _validationTypes.email };
      } else if (settings.validateDate && elem.is('input[type="date"]')) {
        var doesPass;
        if (elem.val().trim() === '') {
          doesPass = true;
        } else if (isNaN(Date.parse(elem.val()))) {
          doesPass = false;
        } else if (elem.prop('max') && !isNaN(Date.parse(elem.prop('max'))) && Date.parse(elem.val()) > Date.parse(elem.prop('max'))) {
          doesPass = false;
        } else if (elem.prop('min') && !isNaN(Date.parse(elem.prop('min'))) && Date.parse(elem.val()) < Date.parse(elem.prop('min'))) {
          doesPass = false;
        } else {
          doesPass = true;
        }
        return { isValid: doesPass, type: _validationTypes.date };
      } else if (settings.validateNumber && elem.is('input[type="number"]')) {
        var doesPass;
        if (elem.val().trim() === '') {
          doesPass = true;
        } else if (isNaN(parseFloat(elem.val()))) {
          doesPass = false;
        } else if (elem.prop('max') && !isNaN(parseFloat(elem.prop('max'))) && parseFloat(elem.val()) > parseFloat(elem.prop('max'))) {
          doesPass = false;
        } else if (elem.prop('min') && !isNaN(parseFloat(elem.prop('min'))) && parseFloat(elem.val()) < parseFloat(elem.prop('min'))) {
          doesPass = false;
        } else {
          doesPass = true;
        }
        return { isValid: doesPass, type: _validationTypes.number };
      } else {
        return { isValid: true };
      }
    }
  }

  function setFieldName(elem){
    if (typeof(elem.data('error-msg')) !== 'undefined' && elem.data('error-msg') !== '') {
      return;
    }
    var elemName;
    var forLabel = $(_reqForm).find('label[for="' + elem.attr('id') + '"]');
    if (forLabel.length > 0 && $(forLabel[0]).text() !== '') {
      elemName = $(forLabel[0]).text();
    } else {
      elemName = elem.attr('name');
    }
    elem.data('error-name', elemName);
  }

  function getFieldMessage(elem, resultType){
    var elemMsg;
    if (typeof(elem.data('error-msg')) !== 'undefined' && elem.data('error-msg') !== '') {
      elemMsg = elem.data('error-msg');
    } else {
      elemMsg = elem.data('error-name') + resultType.msg;
    }
    return elemMsg;
  }

  function showFieldError(elem, fieldMsg){
    if (isRadioGroup(elem)) {
      elem.parents('fieldset').first().addClass('invalid');
      if (settings.showFieldIndicator){
        elem.parents('fieldset').first().find('.error-indicator').first().text(fieldMsg).attr('aria-hidden', false);
      }
    } else {
      elem.addClass('invalid');
      if (settings.showFieldIndicator){
        elem.nextAll('.error-indicator').first().text(fieldMsg).attr('aria-hidden', false);
      }
    }
  }

  function clearFieldError(elem){
    if (isRadioGroup(elem)) {
      elem.parents('fieldset').removeClass('invalid');
      if (settings.showFieldIndicator){
        elem.parents('fieldset').first().find('.error-indicator').first().attr('aria-hidden', true);
      }
      var firstInGroup = $(_reqForm).find('input[name="' + elem.attr('name') + '"]').first();
      var summaryItem = $('#errorSummary li a[data-field="' + firstInGroup.attr('id') + '"]');
      if (summaryItem.length > 0) {
        summaryItem.parent('li').remove();
        if ($('#errorSummary ul li').length === 0) {
          $('#errorSummary').remove();
        }
      }
    } else {
      elem.removeClass('invalid');
      if (settings.showFieldIndicator){
        elem.nextAll('.error-indicator').first().attr('aria-hidden', true);
      }
      var summaryItem = $('#errorSummary li a[data-field="' + elem.attr('id') + '"]');
      if (summaryItem.length > 0) {
        summaryItem.parent('li').remove();
        if ($('#errorSummary ul li').length === 0) {
          $('#errorSummary').remove();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function showErrorSummary(errorMsgList){
    var errorSummary = $(_summaryTemplate.replace('{0}', settings.errorSummaryMsg));
    var errorList = $('<ul></ul>');

    for (var i=0; i < errorMsgList.length; i++) {
      var errorLink = $('<a href="#" data-field="' + errorMsgList[i].elem + '">' + errorMsgList[i].msg + '</a>');
      errorLink.click(function(){ jumpToElem($(this).data('field')); return false; });
      var errorItm = $('<li></li>');
      errorItm.append(errorLink);
      errorList.append(errorItm);
    }

    errorSummary.append(errorList).prependTo($(_reqForm));
    errorSummary.focus();
  }

  function isRadioGroup(elem){
    return (elem.is('input[type="radio"]') && typeof(elem.attr('name')) !== 'undefined' && elem.attr('name') !== '');
  }

  function jumpToElem(fieldId){
    $(_reqForm).find('#' + fieldId).focus();
  }

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: First off, indent the code properly and you might ***see*** what is wrong, as of now it is more or less impossible to follow

Comment: easy - javascript doesn't do anything simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear with your question very well but if you want to load one script file after loading an another script file. You can simple load using $.when() and $.getScript() jquery functions like this.

$.getScript() will load javascript file asynchronously and .done() call back of $.when() method will continue after the loading script done.

This is a very simple sample.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script>
          $.when(
              $.getScript("/mypath/validation.js")

           ).done(function(){
             $.getScript("/mypath/AjaxCall.js")
           });
    </script>
</body>
```

Hope it might help.